# How should I move the Wiimote to fight Bokoblins?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Bokoblins are a very common enemy in Skyward Sword, and they're clever enough to anticipate your swings and block them. I'd like to kill them in a much smoother fashion than I have been. What movements do Bokoblins read, and how can I ensure I always swing where they're vulnerable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Bokoblins** are actually not too difficult to fight, they're not very smart if you know how to attack them.

When fighting them, just keep alternating between left and right horizontal strikes, maybe throw in a **Spin Attack** or two.  Don't stop if they block, just keep swinging.  It takes at most 3 hits to knock them down and possibly a **Fatal Blow** to kill them off.  Just beware when in groups, you might have to dodge backward immediately after knocking one down or you might get hit from one of the others.

The thing is, they will only block in a certain direction and hold that direction for a second or two.  So if you swing from the right and they block, they should be open on the left and that's where you hit them.  In groups, it might be tricky since you might be hitting one but another one will block and you might not connect with the second hit, just dodge back just in case.

---

Later in the game, you'll encounter **Electric Bokoblins** which nullifies this tactic.  With these guys, a block means a shock to you so you'll have to use more conventional tactics.  These really work with almost any enemy in general.  If one approach doesn't work, try the next.

Perhaps the easiest way to deal with them would be to use a **Skyward Strike** on them.  As long as you swing it in their direction, it will always connect and knock them down giving you an opportunity to deal the **Finishing Blow**.

The next thing to try would be to use the **Shield Bash** when *they* attack so that *you* can counter.  You will want to have the **Sacred Shield** (or better) in this case that way you won't get electrocuted (and you wouldn't want the **Wooden Shield** at this point in the game).

Alternatively if you want to be the aggressor, this can be somewhat difficult to pull off due to the awkwardness of the motions.  Choose a direction (left or right) to point the tip of your WiiMote to while moving the rest of your arm in the other direction.  This should draw their guard to the side you are pointing.  This is where you can swing your arm in the direction pointed to (or flick your wrist) to perform an "opposite" attack.

As a last resort, you'll have to bite the bullet and dodge their attacks and counter.  Use your best judgement there on which directions to dodge.  Overhead attacks could be dodged left, right or back.  Attacks from the right should be dodged moving left or back.  And reverse that for attacks from the left.

Comment: This holding defense thing is a recurring theme with enemies in this game, so it helps if you know how to deal with it.  Later enemies are not as forgiving for blocked attacks.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good thing to point out.  Forgot to mention the electric ones.  For those enemies, you can't rely on the blocking tactic.

Comment: The electric ones can't shock you through a wooden shield.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Clearly, but why would you want a wooden shield at that point in the game?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: You can't get the sacred shield from the shop till after you've completed Lanayru Mining Facility

Comment: @deworde: Ah good point, I actually don't remember when exactly it was first available.  Still, I never really used the shield until the final few bosses.  So it probably won't be too much of a problem without it as Bokoblins are really the only electrical threat.

Answer (score 1):

Electric Bokoblins:

Method 1: Attack them when they open themselves up as they attempt an attack.

Method 2: Once they switch their guard position you should immediately follow up by attacking them at the spot they just switched from. It works every time.

Method 3: if they haven't spotted you yet, you can dash at them and swing the wii-mote to do a running jump attack which will knock them down, giving you an opportunity to do a finishing strike.

Answer (score 0):

vs the ordinary bobkins, I would always juke my sword left and right, then execute a vertical spin attack.

I don't think it worked that well.

If you shoot them with the scattershot/slingshot you can stun them.

If you are having trouble, I think it's easiest just to dodge backwards, then run in for a horizontal spin attack.